# How to retrieve data in laravel eloquent WITH & DISTINCT or GROUPBY?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to get countries as `groupBy`. Unfortunately it's not working.

Controller

```
public function create()
    {
        $tender_id = TenderMaster::select('id')->with('Ports')->get();
        return $tender_id;

    }
```

Model Relationship

```
public function Ports()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tender_Module\Masters\Air\AirPortCode','hmsc_bid_origin_port_comm','bid_id','port_id')->select('id','ap_city','ap_country');
  }
```

Result

> [{"id":213,"ports":[{"id":52,"ap_city":"ALLENTOWN,
>   PA","ap_country":"United States of
>   America","pivot":{"bid_id":213,"port_id":52}},{"id":922,"ap_city":"MACON,
>   GA","ap_country":"United States of
>   America","pivot":{"bid_id":213,"port_id":922}},{"id":903,"ap_city":"LUBBOCK,
>   TX","ap_country":"United States of
>   America","pivot":{"bid_id":213,"port_id":903}},{"id":800,"ap_city":"KUSHIRO","ap_country":"JAPAN","pivot":{"bid_id":213,"port_id":800}},{"id":917,"ap_city":"MAASTRICHT/AACHEN","ap_country":"NETHERLANDS","pivot":{"bid_id":213,"port_id":917}}]}]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow chamodtcr!

Currently your question is quite vague on why your code isn't working. I'd recommend editing your question to include more detail on the problem particularly any code errors you get.

Comment: @VikasKatariya it's not working